# About Python global variable

Tags: python, global-variables

```
    import sys
    from threading import Thread

    is_online=1

    class CommandListenerThread(Thread):
        global is_online
        def run(self):
          while is_online:
             next_command=sys.stdin.readlines();
             if next_command == 'exit':
                 is_online=0
             else:
                 print next_command



    listener=CommandListenerThread()
    listener.start()
```

When I run this python code,it shows an error:  **"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'is_online' referenced before assignment"**

I tested another code which uses the same way to access the global variable inside a class,and it works fine.  So,what is wrong with this specific code?

the code may look weird which using a thread to listen the command line,but it is just
a part of my program which gets an error when I run the whole program.

thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `global is_online` into `run()` to solve the error.

To address your other question (in a comment below), why not make it a static class variable ?

```
class CommandListenerThread(Thread):    
    is_online = 1    
    def run(self):
        print CommandListenerThread.is_online
```

In case that you have to use another code with a global `is_online`, you can take the DI (dependency injection) approach as follows:

import sys
from threading import Thread

```
is_online = 2

class CommandListenerThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, is_online):
        super(CommandListenerThread, self).__init__()       
        CommandListenerThread.is_online = is_online # now it's a static member
                                                    # if you want to make it an instance member use self.is_online

    def run(self):
        print CommandListenerThread.is_online        

listener=CommandListenerThread(is_online) # inject the value to the constructor 
listener.start()
```

Comment: Yeah,solved.  So..Does it mean if I have n functions in a class which all need to access the global var x, I need to declare x as global inside each of these functions?

Comment: Why do you need it to be global? can't it be a class variable ? see above

Comment: In my program,it has to be. The code above is just a testing code I created with the same pattern of a part of my original code where encounters a problem.    In my program var "is_online" is shared by multiple classes.thanks

Comment: @user3788871 I'll add another approach in a minute

Comment: What you mean in the second method is passing the global variable as a parameter to the class constructor. Are you sure that python passes reference to a function instead of a copy?

Comment: @user3788871 As I already wrote, if you want a reference to the global variable - declare it as global inside `run()`.